# Writing asynchronous to a .txt on a USB Stick - C# on Windows IoT

Tags: c#, file, logging, stream

I have Troubles to write more than one time on the txt-file. First time it works fine but even if i try the GetFileAsynchronous-Method the File is just overwritten. How do I solve this Problem?

```
public async void write(string errormessage)
{
    StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();

    if (externalDrives.Count > 0)
    {
        StorageFolder removalableDrive = externalDrives[3];
        String filename  = "log_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Day 
            + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Month + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Year 
            + "-" + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Hours
            + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Minutes + "_" 
            + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Seconds + ".txt";
        StorageFile file = await removalableDrive.CreateFileAsync(filename);                
        Stream w         = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        StreamWriter sw  = new StreamWriter(w);
        sw.WriteLine("\n" + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Hours + ":" + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Minutes + ":" + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Seconds + ":    " + errormessage);
        sw.Dispose();
    }            
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would expect `CreateFileAsync` should do that unless you use the overload with `CreationCollisionOption`

Comment: Yeah thats right but i still can't write a second line in the file - still overwritten.

Comment: You should look into `String.Format` or c# 6 string interpolation to make this code more readable.

Comment: You need to seek file stream to the end before writing into it, otherwise you'll overwrite the beginning of the file.

Comment: Can you give me an example for that?